# If URL X contains THIS, then onclick of link will take you to URL Y?

Tags: jquery, window.location

I am trying to create a link which leads to different URL's depending on what your current URL is.

So if you're on product page "Cat" and click "link-with-arrow" on the page, it will lead you to "More Cats". And if you start from "Dog", you'll end up in "More Dogs" by onclick.

This is what I have thought of so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
if(window.location.href.indexOf("cats") > -1) {
   onclick("\"link--with-arrow\"window.location=\"https://more.cats.com\">");
}
```

})

Any thoughts on how to make this work?

Comment: What is this random onclick line? You have a function called `onclick`?

Comment: My attempt to get the onclick working as simply as possible. This was 'function' before.

Comment: well you need to bind the onclick to the element

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  if(window.location.href.indexOf("cats") != -1) {
    document.location.href = "https://more.cats.com\";
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  if(window.location.href.indexOf("cats") > -1) {
     jQuery('#clickme').on('click', function(e){
      window.location = "https://example.com";
     });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="clickme">Click me</button>
```